# "Class def default" is only partially working in Mermaid

Tags: css, markdown, mermaid, obsidian

I’m quite confused as to how classDef default works with Mermaid Graphs. I want a flowchart where I **don’t need** to add a style tag to each node. Mermaid Doc says that I should just add classDef default  and it should change every node, that doesn’t has a class attached to it, to this default-settings. However, trying it out with this Diagram

```
flowchart LR
δ:
B:::hidden --> 0
0((q<sub>0)) -->|a|1(((q<sub>1)))
1(((q<sub>1))) -->|b| 1(((q<sub>1)))
0((q<sub>0</sub>)) -->|a| 2(((q<sub>2)))
2(((q<sub>2))) -->|c| 2(((q<sub>2)))
classDef default stroke:white
```

I - for some reason - only get the single circled nodes to have a white stroke, while the double-circled nodes stay transparent. Adding style  stroke:white however does work.

[image: Graph with style <node> stroke:white] Result of `style <node> stroke:white`

[image: Graph with classDef default stroke:white] Result of `classDef default`

> Note, I'm not using a standalone version of `Mermaid` but instead the integrated version of `Mermaid` inside `Obsidian`.